# Frequently check a file while subprocess is writing to it

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following piece of code where the c++ executable (`run.out`) prints out a bunch of info in the runtime using `std::cout`. This code stores the outputs of `run.out` into the `storage.txt`.

```
storage = open("storage.txt", "w")
shell_cmd = "run.out" 
proc = subprocess.Popen([shell_cmd], stdout=storage, stderr=storage)
```

Once the `subprocess` starts, I need to frequently check the contents of `storage.txt` and decide based on what has just been stored in there. How may I do that?

Comment: Do you _need_ to write the output to a file? If not, you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) to start `run.out` and capture its output. [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) in particular would allow you to read stdout as it's being produced.

Comment: What do you mean, reading `storage.txt` while the subprocess is running ?

Comment: @kalatabe
I know that it's much easier to have `stdout=subprocess .PIPE` but for a couple of reasons I have to write to the file.

Comment: Beware, writing to a file (or a pipe) is often buffered at OS level. You may have to write several ko before anything to be visible in the file...

Comment: @MauriceMeyer
exactly, while the subprocess is writing to it, I want to read the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`subprocess.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=poll#subprocess.Popen.poll) which returns immediately and indicates if the subprocess is still running:

```
while proc.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.25)  # reads the content 4 times a seconds!
    data = open("storage.txt").read()
    if 'error' in data:
        print("failed ...")
        # somesomething ...
```